# Java Map Generic

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

the top map has 3 sub maps and each sub map has different object.

like the following code, how can I add generic to the map top?

```
    Map<String,Map> top = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map>();

    Map<String,TypeA> subA = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,TypeA>();
    Map<Long,TypeB> subB = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,TypeB>();
    Map<String, long[]> sbuC = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,TypeC>();
    top.put("SUB_A", subA);
    top.put("SUB_B", subB);
    top.put("SUB_C", subC);
```

Comment: This looks like it _shouldn't_ be in a `Map` -- it should be in an `Object` with strongly typed fields, not all shoved into a `Map` which will require unsafe casting.

Comment: it's from old application. we read files, convert to Object and put them into Gemfire. now I am looking for a quick way to remove Gemfire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String,Map<<? extends  Object,?>> top = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map< <? extends Object,?>>();
```

Key is an `object` and the value is any type.

Comment: I tried, get this "The method put(String, Map<Object,?>) in the type Map<String,Map<Object,?>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map<String,long[]>)"

Comment: `Map<String,Map<? extends Object,?>> top = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<? extends Object,?>>();` avoids that compile error for me. Also, `Map<String,Map<?,?>> top = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` works.  Both seem pretty weird looking to me, though.

Comment: @user3644708 have changed my answer

Comment: thanks all, it works. @azurefrog, how could I update it? can you please show me more info? thanks